# Remove /views/ from url with rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to learn how to use htaccess rewrite, but I just can't get the hang of it. What I'm trying to do is make the following urls:

```
mysite.com/
mysite.com/views/clients
mysite.com/views/projects
mysite.com/views/estimates
```

...look like this:

```
mysite.com/
mysite.com/clients
mysite.com/projects
mysite.com/estimates
```

It should be simple enough. But I just can't make it work.

Comment: What have you tried? Just to confirm... the URLs already look like `mysite.com/clients` in your application?

Comment: I've lost track og all the codes I've tried :)

We have a directory called /views/ (f.i. views/clients/index.html), where we put all our modules. We want our customers to see the url mysite.com/clients, but the files will be located in the views directory.

Comment: Yes, but any client-side links are already of the form `mysite.com/clients`, not `mysite.com/views/clients`? Just confirming, since that is stage#1, but for some reason many people seem to miss that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the URLs in your app are already of the form `/clients`, not `/views/clients`, then try the following in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "views" from all (typed) URLs with external redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /views/([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule .* /%1 [R,L]

# Internally rewrite specific requests back to /views
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(clients|projects|estimates)/(.*) /views/$1/$2 [L]
```

Once you are satisfied this is working then change the `R` (temporary) redirect to `R=301` (permanent).

This checks against `THE_REQUEST` before the redirect in order to prevent a redirect loop.

Comment: That changes the url, but returns a not found message:
"The requested URL /projects was not found on this server."

Comment: Actually it works, but only with an / at the end. mysite.com/clients - displays an error. mysite.com/clients/ - works. But that's okay though. Thank you very much.